# Why use preprocessor #if statements instead of if() else?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I see this being done all the time for example in the Linux Kernel. What is the purpose of using the preprocessor commands vs just normal C++ if else block? Is there a speed advantage or something?

Comment: Do you know what the preprocessor does?

Comment: `If it's a bad question than it will probably get removed by the mods.` No, it won't. Questions don't get deleted unless they go against the rules (i.e. they're spam or hate-speech or similar), or are closed and don't have an upvoted answer for a long time. This question *will not* and *should not* be deleted.

Comment: @Konrad, that's kind of the point.  He's asking a question to learn what the preprocessor does.  No need to deride him.  This is a question answer site.  You know the answer, so just answer the question, don't complain about it.  I assume that your weren't born knowing what the preprocessor does.  Neither was kjh

Comment: @Scott No derision. A reply would have informed the kind of answer that was appropriate here. That said, there’s kind of an agreement that questions which are answered by a basic textbook are not that appropriate for Stack Overflow, because answering them is best done in a textbook fashion, and not in a sketchy short text that, by necessity, will gloss over many important details.

Comment: @Konrad, that's fair. That probably brings up a broader issue that SO has become the top search result for many of these type of questions.  Whether it likes it or not, SO is becoming the 'textbook'. It's not good enough to say 'Google it' anymore as SO is the Google result (infinite loop). I already knew about preprocessors, so this was not useful to me, but I can see how others could stumble upon it.

Comment: And even knowing *what* a preprocessor doesn't mean that someone would immediately understand when to use it. There are many things that can be done with a preprocessor and without one.

Comment: @Scott: Unfortunately this situation has produced a generation of developers with no interest or skill in _reading the documentation_, which is of astronomical concern.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A preprocessor changes the C/C++ code *before* it gets compiled (hence *pre* processor).

Preprocessor ifs are evaluated at **compile-time**.

C/C++ ifs are evaluated at **run-time**.

---

You can do things that can't be done at run-time.

Adjust code for different platforms or different compilers:

```
#ifdef __unix__ /* __unix__ is usually defined by compilers targeting Unix systems */
#include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32 /* _Win32 is usually defined by compilers targeting 32 or 64 bit Windows systems */
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

Ensure header file definitions are included only once (equivalent of `#pragma once`, but more portable):

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

class Example { ... };

#endif
```

---

You can make things faster than at run-time.

```
void some_debug_function() {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Debug!\n");
#endif
}
```

Now, when compiling with `DEBUG` not defined (likely a command line parameter to your compiler), any calls to `some_debug_function` can be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Although the conditional include syntax is supported by pretty much any compiler, much cleaner way also supported by the majority of available compilers is to use "#pragma once" and not clutter global preprocessor name space.

Comment: `if(DEBUG) printf("foo\n");` will also be optimized away to nothing (assuming `printf` is visible) with `#define DEBUG 0` so you might want to tweak that part.

Comment: @Yakk: Most compilers will optimize out `if (constantFalseCondition) doSomething()`, or even a call to a compiler-visible function which can be determined to never do anything.  On the other hand, if conditional "debug" statements need to use a global buffer which isn't used for anything else, an `#ifdef` can refrain from allocating the buffer when it isn't needed; conditional-execution statements cannot.

Comment: @Supercat agreed: which is why the point is valid, but the example is poor.

Comment: @Yakk: I've read many people commenting that languages shouldn't have things like `#if` because compilers can detect and eliminate dead code.  A major problem with such thinking is that most linkers cannot eliminate dead global variables, and I don't think any can eliminate 99.9%-dead variables (which are used only by code that puts values there in anticipation of their being needed).

Answer (score 10):

Preprocessor is run before the compilation pass, so the compiler won't even see anything that was in  the not-taken #if branch.

```
#if DEBUG
int a;
#else
double b;
#endif
```

gcc -c -DDEBUG=1 file.c will see "int a"

gcc -c file.c will see "double b"

Answer (score 5):

Preprocessor allows you to actually cut out or paste in to your source file, code to be compiled. If its cut out, its gone, its like a comment, does nothing, is not compiled, produces no code in the binary. Devs will often use this technique to add code only in debug build for debugging purposes or for adding or excluding code for specific operating systems.